# Cannot access IP on local network but can internet

Tags: linux, networking, routes

I am facing a peculiar problem . I have a http server running on one computer (say computer A) . I can access this server from one computer(say computer B) but not from another (OS Ubuntu )(say computer C) in same network (Local network).
The computer C has no problems accessing Internet but cannot access http server on computer A in same network . Computer A and computer C have no problem pinging each other . Please Help.

Comment: If ping works, the next step would be to try *telnet*, and, to check the firewalls. Didn't have to do that the last decade, so much of the details may have changed since, so I don't trust myself to state the commands to do this.

Comment: I will try telnet and post results today

Answer (score 0):

Can computer C ping computers A or B?
What is the netmask set for on all of the computers? Does the netmask of the router match that on the computers?

Comment: Yes C can ping computer A and B . Netmask set on all three computers and on router is 255.255.255.0